# Mongo Document Structure

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-java

I am looking to store some time series data into mondodb. The system outputs data every minute and as such I have made an array called hours. This array is 24 in size (represeing hours in the day). Each hour contains an array of size 60 (every minute of that hour).

The example below shows 5 hours with each hour having only 3, 3,5,3,2 minutes of data respectively.

At the end of each day I will update the document with hourly averages etc...

I did it like this as when it maps to a POJO it is very easy to find the correct hour and minute just by using the array indexes.

Good Link.
http://blog.mongodb.org/post/65517193370/schema-design-for-time-series-data-in-mongodb

The use case is simply to allow charting at the various granularities. Everything from minutes to days.

```
 {
   "_id": ObjectId("55eee516b932c564bc8dd645"),
  "name": "James",
   "hours": [
     [
       1.12,
       2.47,
       3.25
    ],
     [
       4.12,
       5.24,
       6.21
    ],
     [
       7.25,
       8.69,
       9.54,
       NumberInt(5),
       6.36
    ],
     [
       10.55,
       11.45,
       NumberInt(12)
    ],
     [
       13.14,
       14.23
    ]
  ]
}
```

Does using the array approach over the nested document as in the link example cause any issues when updating as so and when averaging etc...

```
db.metrics.update(
  { 
    timestamp_hour: ISODate("2013-10-10T23:00:00.000Z"),
    type: “memory_used”
  }, 
  {$set: {“values.59.59”: 2000000 } }
)
```

Comment: Have you already reviewed http://blog.mongodb.org/post/65517193370/schema-design-for-time-series-data-in-mongodb? I am using the document-oriented approach and it works fine.

Comment: Also "at the end of each day" is not a smart process. You can basically do this "directly" or "periodically" and a lot more frequent if you have a set structure to "increment" counters within grouped values. But voting to close since without a "use case" for your intended usgeage of the data this is a purely academic and "Opion based" question. "Usage" is the prime consideration of all NoSQL modelling concerns. Be "clear" and you get my reopen vote ( or retracttion, whichever comes first ), and maybe an answer.

Comment: Having read you link I guess the question is .. is there any issue with using the Array as I have above over using the document approach where they have it nested.